# ext4 restore backup: deleteino: out of range 0

Tags: linux, backup, ext4, restore, dump

I'm trying to use (dump) restore -command to restore linux ext4 file system from an incremental backup. I'm using a hanoi tower strategy to make the backups, and the dumps look like as follows, sorted by time:

```
root@server:/backup# ls -alth
-rw-r--r--  1 backup backup  264305457 Oct  2 22:05 l2-phz-xvda2-001
-rw-r--r--  1 backup backup  755017563 Nov  3 22:13 l1-phz-xvda2-001
-rw-r--r--  1 backup backup    1734399 Nov 11 22:00 l4-phz-xvda2-001
-rw-r--r--  1 backup backup  498703367 Nov 19 22:08 l3-phz-xvda2-001
-rw-r--r--  1 backup backup 2304401315 Jan  1 22:47 l0-phz-xvda2-001
-rw-r--r--  1 backup backup     933481 Jan  5 22:00 l5-phz-xvda2-001
-rw-r--r--  1 backup backup  122383278 Jan  6 22:02 l7-phz-xvda2-001
-rw-r--r--  1 backup backup  122803554 Jan  7 22:02 l6-phz-xvda2-001
```

Since the level 0 -dump is a full dump, I first restored that, but when I try to restore the next (l5) dump, I get the following error message:

```
restore -rMf /backup/l5-phz-xvda2- -b 256
Dump tape is compressed.
deleteino: out of range 0
abort? [yn] n
deleteino: 0 not found
abort? [yn] n
deleteino: out of range 0
abort? [yn] y
dump core? [yn] y
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any suggestions how to restore the incremental dumps?